# Bash array loop only takes the first entry

Tags: bash

Good evening,

i just try to stop some docker containers defined in an array.
But only the first one is stopped but four times.

`CONTAINERTOSTOP=(webgrabplus Nextcloud ddclient MariaDB-10.6)`

```
for constopping in "${CONTAINERTOSTOP[@]}"; do                      
docker container stop $CONTAINERTOSTOP done
```

My script only stops the webgrabplus container but for four times so
i think the loop works.

Where is my fault here ?

Comment: `docker container stop "$constopping"; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop just using (without loop):

```
CONTAINERTOSTOP=(webgrabplus Nextcloud ddclient MariaDB-10.6)
docker stop "${CONTAINERTOSTOP[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes you cant find the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 4):

You are stopping `$CONTAINERTOSTOP`. You want `$constopping`.

You are also either missing a `;` or a newline after the `docker` command.

```
for constopping in "${CONTAINERTOSTOP[@]}"
do
    docker container stop "$constopping"
done
```

(Of course, @ufopilot's answer is even better in the specific case, but I let my answer stand for the "**if** you want a loop..." case.)

Comment: and since `$CONTAINERTOSTOP == ${CONTAINERTOSTOP[0]} == webgrabplus` the stop is issued against `webgrabplus` 4 times

Comment: Better to quote `"$constopping"`